# Azure SQL Database import from REST API

Tags: rest, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-sql-database

Does Azure offer any services to import data from a REST API into SQL Azure?  Worse case we can do this via .NET, but I thought there might be an easier way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by import data from rest api? Will rest api not publish it to some store ?

Comment: We access to a 3rd party rest api. We wish to pull some of this into our own DB for reporting purposes.

Comment: @DanielMackay Did you find a solution yet? I am using Function App to bring the data in.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi - no solution yet.  Was trying to find a simple solution via DataFactory or LogicApps, but nothing good so far.  It's possible for both, but I feel like there should be an easier way.

Comment: @DanielMackay I posted a new question to seek answers [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812089/bringing-incremental-data-in-from-rest-apis-into-sql-azure].

Comment: I also  posted in Azure slack channel, hoping to get some answers

Answer (score -2):

The documentation link below explains how to use REST API to import data into your Azure SQL Database.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt683388.aspx

Is this helpful?

Comment: This isn't what was asked for. They asked about integrating 3rd party data via an API into Azure